# Interference Diversity for management of inter-cell interference in cellular communications

Tags: digital-communications

What is interference diversity? and how is it different in CDMA and OFDM? I have a problem understanding the concept
Reference book: Fundamentals of Wireless Communications, chapter3/4 Author: David Tse

Comment: Again, as asked on multiple of your previous questions: don't just use as many tags as possible. Your question has nothing to do with [tag:electronic-warfare], at all. Also, words depend on context. so, please tell us in which context (a link to a paper) you've read "interference diversity": I've done a fair bit of work with diversity schemes, and read a few fundamental papers on interference alignment in cellular networks, but I don't think I've ever come across that term. In any case, diversity techniques are simply in a different category than CDMA/OFDM, and can't be directly compared.

Comment: I'm not fixing the tags on this quesiton and downvoting: you never fixed your tags on previous questions.

Comment: You're wrong when you say "diversity techniques are simply in a different category than CDMA/OFDM"

Comment: Read "Fundamentals of Wireless Communications" chapter 4 and you will know that you're wrong! Anyway thank as you  seem to be the only one who at least answers my questions!

Comment: "Fundamentals of Wireless Communications" by David Tse is one of the best books written about wireless communications, and the term interference diversity is mentioned there. But now let me ask you a question: Why do many people  believe that whatever they never heard of before or never encountered before or simply do not know, must be false or wrong? this observation has been puzzling me for years! Do you have an answer?

Comment: I do happen to have that on my bookshelf, yes, and you're right, I missed how Tse and Viswanath call interference averaging "interference diversity", that's why adding references to your question is important(**PLEASE** fix your question in that respect, and finally fix the tags.). Notice I've never said it was wrong,I just said it needed context. Also, if you've actually read chapter 1–3 you'll see how OFDM and CDMA are doing different things,and then interference diversity is in a different category of things. What you're asking is like "how do Christianity and Apples compare to Integrals?".

Comment: to say this specifically: OFDM is a method to distribute data in a unidirectional link across subcarriers to mitigate the multipath aspect, CDMA is a multi-access scheme, and interference diversity is a way of employing diversity to make things more robust in communication networks. Three different things with three different purposes, which all can be combined with each other.

Comment: Thank you for responding . However I believe you are missing the point when it comes to the expression "interference diversity" either for CDMA or OFDM.

Comment: In chapter 3 he talks about diversity as a means of averaging the channel fluctuations (fading) and thus making it look more and more like an AWGN channel. In chapter 4 he talks about something else: that is averaging now the intercell interference and making it less fluctuating.  I understand the first part in chapter 3 as far as the signal of interest is concerned but then I wasn't sure that it also applies to the undesired intercell interference as well! i.e. averaging the fluctuation of the interfering signal which he calls interference diversity

Comment: You make interesting points, but I've decided to not interact with them until you fix your questions (all) by 1. removing the ostensibly unrelated tags, and 2. fix this question by adding the Tse/Viswanath reference to it.